# IIS windows server 2012 r2 - error app framework 2.0

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an application using framework 2.0 normalmento is running on a windows server 2003 server after migrating to windows server 2012 r2 I am not able to open. generating this error:

> Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion'. Note que attribute names are case-sensitive.

In the application settings within iis is already configured for Framework 2.0 pool.

Someone has gone through something like this?

print:
http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/iis_error-jpg

Comment: The attribute [controlRenderingCompatibiltyVersion is only supported for .Net Frame 4.0 (or higher)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.controlrenderingcompatibilityversion%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: ok thanks for this app worked. Modified the webconfig to 4.0 framework not giving this more the error will take the test in every application to see if everything's working.